# svg img only loads after text tag(h1/h2/h3/p)?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

**Context**
I'm trying to create a standard navbar using tailwind css framework.

**Blocker**
Whenever I try to load the svg logo without a h/p tag, in the example below - "Temp", it doesn't load.

```css
body {
    background-image: url('https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/rAiYTfKGqDCRIIqo664sY9XZIvQ.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>MovieApp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/css.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header class="mx-96 flex items-center justify-between">
    <div>
        <h1>temp</h1>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="../static/img/tmdb.svg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Temporary text</h1>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</html>
```

**SVG:**

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 407.34 160.81"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#01d277}</style></defs><title>PoweredByRectangle_Green</title><path class="cls-1" d="M50.38 102.47h6.94V74.71h8.64v-6.89H41.74v6.89h8.64v27.76zM88.53 102.47h6.94v-34.7h-6.94v13.88H78.14V67.77H71.2v34.7h6.94V88.59h10.39v13.88zM121.25 95.53h-13.02v-6.94h11.12v-6.94h-11.12v-6.94h12.43v-6.94h-19.38v34.7h19.97v-6.94zM157.79 82.54L144.1 67.3h-2.23v35.24h7.03V83.17l8.89 9.32 8.88-9.32-.05 19.37h7.04V67.3h-2.19l-13.68 15.24z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M3309.1 1841.93c-23.88 0-23.88 35.77 0 35.77s23.9-35.77 0-35.77zm0 28.59c-13.88 0-13.88-21.45 0-21.45s13.9 21.45 0 21.45z" transform="translate(-3111.93 -1774.68)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M254.5 67.83h6.94v34.7h-6.94zM274.19 95.6v-6.94h11.13v-6.94h-11.13v-6.94h12.44v-6.95h-19.38v34.71h19.96V95.6h-13.02z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M3429.48 1842.91h-10.34v34.7h10.34c23.1 0 23.1-34.7 0-34.7zm0 27.76h-3.4v-20.82h3.4c13.52 0 13.52 20.82 0 20.82z" transform="translate(-3111.93 -1774.68)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M3472.7 1860.23c2.18-1.5 3.11-4.22 3.2-6.84.15-6.12-3.69-10.53-9.85-10.53h-13.74v34.75H3466a10.32 10.32 0 0 0 10.24-10.44 8.43 8.43 0 0 0-3.54-6.94zm-13.4-10.44h6.17a3.51 3.51 0 0 1 0 7h-6.17v-7zm6.17 20.87h-6.17v-6.94h6.17a3.41 3.41 0 0 1 3.49 3.45 3.45 3.45 0 0 1-3.49 3.5z" transform="translate(-3111.93 -1774.68)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M233.13 86.57L224 67.83h-8.01l16.37 35.44h1.55l16.37-35.44h-8.01l-9.14 18.74z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M3494.78 1920.93c14.6 0 24.48-9.88 24.48-24.48v-97.28c0-14.6-9.88-24.48-24.48-24.48h-358.37c-14.6 0-24.48 9.88-24.48 24.48v136.33l12.56-14.56v-121.77a11.94 11.94 0 0 1 11.92-11.92h358.37a11.94 11.94 0 0 1 11.92 11.92v97.28a11.94 11.94 0 0 1-11.92 11.92H3155l-12.56 12.56-.08-.1z" transform="translate(-3111.93 -1774.68)"/><path class="cls-1" d="M3154.3 1827.53v-15h5.9c5.84 0 5.82 9.26 0 9.26h-2.9v5.73h-3zm5.65-8.65c2 0 2-3.36 0-3.36h-2.65v3.36h2.65zM3176.07 1812.27c10.33 0 10.33 15.47 0 15.47s-10.33-15.47 0-15.47zm0 3.09c-6 0-6 9.28 0 9.28s6.01-9.29 0-9.29zM3193.12 1827.85l-6.15-15.33h3.38l3 7.66 2.94-7.52h.15l2.94 7.52 3-7.66h3.38l-6.13 15.26h-.55l-2.75-6.66-2.73 6.72h-.52zM3209.53 1827.53v-15h7.47v3h-4.51v3h3.95v3h-3.95v3h4.77v3h-7.77zM3229.47 1827.53l-3-5.73H3225v5.73h-3v-15h5.92c5.35 0 5.88 7.54 1.47 8.82l3.49 6.19h-3.4zm-4.47-8.65h2.65c2 0 2-3.36 0-3.36H3225v3.36zM3236.76 1827.53v-15h7.52v3h-4.51v3h3.95v3h-3.95v3h4.77v3h-7.77zM3253.71 1827.53h-4.47v-15h4.47c9.99-.01 9.99 15 0 15zm-1.47-12v9h1.47c5.84 0 5.84-9 0-9h-1.47zM3291.89 1820.77l-5.23-8.25h3.65l3.07 5.17 3.07-5.17h3.67l-5.25 8.25v6.76h-3v-6.76zM3282.58 1820.18a3.68 3.68 0 0 0 1.39-3 4.13 4.13 0 0 0-4.26-4.56h-5.94v15h5.94a4.46 4.46 0 0 0 4.43-4.51 3.65 3.65 0 0 0-1.56-2.93zm-5.79-4.51h2.67a1.52 1.52 0 0 1 0 3h-2.67v-3zm2.67 9h-2.67v-3h2.67a1.47 1.47 0 0 1 1.51 1.49 1.49 1.49 0 0 1-1.52 1.54z" transform="translate(-3111.93 -1774.68)"/></svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Add relevant code. We aren't able to debug your html/css code from screenshot.

Comment: Code has been added alongside reference to the images.

Comment: Without the h1, the parent div does not get any height any more, and so the image gets 0 x 0 pixels as “dimensions”. Specify at least width or height for your image.

Comment: Many thanks, that has resolved the issue.
Please add as a solution, so that I can mark it as complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this is that you have to consider setting a with and height to the image so that it gets a real displaying space if it is not  a child of any other tag like hs or p.